# How to find all files except those with particular substring in owner name of file

Tags: python, linux, unix, command-line, find

I'm trying to find all files from a certain path except the files owned by users who have "developer" or "admin" within their user name. Can anyone help me achieve this?

I am using the find command to find files. Tried doing this using the -user argument but it failed.

```
find [pathname] -type f -not -user "*admin*"
```

I am also tasked with finding all files where the owner name of the file represents an integer (The owner name is a string, but represents an integer). I know isdigit() returns true if a string represents a positive integer. Would anyone know how to achieve this as well? Thanks.

Comment: is pathname set elsewhere? if so then it should be ```[$pathname]```

Comment: `-user` only does exact matches, not wildcards.

Comment: Nope pathname is within my workspace. I simply typed it like that for generality purposes. And yup, that's what I was assuming when I tried the command above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it directly with `find`, because `-user` does a straight up equality comparison, not wildcard or regular expression matching.

A quick `perl` script that does the job (Pass directory names to search on the command line):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use File::stat;
use User::pwent;
use feature qw/say/;

my %uids; # Cache user information

sub wanted {
    my $st = stat($File::Find::name) or
        (warn "Couldn't stat $File::Find::name: $!\n" && return);
    return unless -f $st; # Only look at regular files
    my $user =
        exists $uids{$st->uid} ? $uids{$st->uid} : $uids{$st->uid} = getpwuid($st->uid);
    # Print filenames owed by uids that don't include developer
    # or admin in a username
    say $File::Find::name if !defined $user || $user->name !~ /developer|admin/;
    # Or defined $user && $user->name =~ /^\d+/ for filtering to usernames that are all digits
    # Or just !defined $user for files owned by uids that don't have /etc/passwd entries
}

find(\&wanted, @ARGV);
```

---

Avoiding `perl`, hmm...

```sh
find pathname -type f -printf "%u\037%p\036" | awk -F"\037" -v RS="\036" '$1 !~ /developer|admin/ { print $2 }'
```

will find files except ones owned by the developer and admin accounts, but for the second part, you can't tell a user id that doesn't have a name apart from a name that's all digits with this approach.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with awk and such. Is there a way to configure the above command to find all files that aren't owned by a user who do have developer or admin in their name rather than the other way around? Would I just add a '!' after the -F?

Comment: @CheeseMan Ooops, I misread your question. See edit.